# Android Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio to run my project and it runs properly in devices with android version 5.1 but it crashes in devices with android version 4.4.4 and i searched a lot but i didn't find any solutions for my problem.any help please.

***Stack Trace:***

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mmido.asfarandroid/com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.TrivelgoB2B.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.TrivelgoB2B.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mmido.asfarandroid-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mmido.asfarandroid-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.TrivelgoB2B.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
t android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***This is my Java Code***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GifImageView gifImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifview);
        try {
            GifDrawable gifDrawable = new GifDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.comp_1);
            gifImageView.setImageDrawable(gifDrawable);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

***Gradle:***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mmido.asfarandroid"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:hfrecyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'



    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':FORTSDKv1.2')
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'){
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'


}
```

***XML File:***

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.TrivelgoB2B.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/new_splash">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/gifview"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: put your java file here

Comment: it crashes in `oncreate` at this line  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` why you need all java code?

Comment: without seeing your code i ca't help you

Comment: i added it now....

Comment: try {
            GifDrawable gifDrawable = new GifDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.comp_1);
            gifImageView.setImageDrawable(gifDrawable);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

try to remove one time and tell me app is crash or not?

Comment: Post your gradle files. You might be missing this dependency.

Comment: which library you are using currently for Gif ??

Comment: @VishalPatoliya what is the difference between my code and yours ? i can't see any difference and if i removed this code it crashes also . problem in setcontentView during rendering layout

Comment: @breakline i added my gradle

Comment: @VishalPatoliya i am using these libraries `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable;`
`pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;`

Comment: Did u use any jar file in libs folder too ?

Comment: @Piyush i don't have libs folder i didn't create it

Comment: Ok first  of all remove _compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')_ because there are 3 same dependencies. Also are you missing _setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);_ in code?

Comment: no it's already exist but dismissed from code i added it now

Comment: can you add the xml file also

Comment: @deepakjohn141 i added xml

Comment: did you set theme for devices prior to 5.1, make sure that your base theme is appcompat

Comment: @deepakjohn141 I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in `mainfest` for all activities

Comment: @AsmaaRashad Nothing wrong with this. Try with _Invalid Cache and Restart_ from _File_ menu

Comment: @Piyush i tried invalid cache and restart but still crashes.. is there any other suggestions?

Comment: Crashing giving the same error?

Comment: @AsmaaRashad I have checked its working fine in 4.4 version too and please remove unnecessary and duplicate dependencies from _build.gradle_ file

Comment: @AsmaaRashad Do you need a test project or u can check with making a new test project?

Comment: could you try with latest version  compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.1'

Comment: @Piyush I never used test projects before so i don't understand you totally

Comment: @deepakjohn141 tried that before but still the same errror

Comment: @AsmaaRashad I have used ur dependency and still it is working fine in all versions

Comment: and i am using same dependency in another project and it works fine also , i can't understand where is the error exactly

Comment: @AsmaaRashad I have told you that u have some duplicates dependencies. You need to remove it first

Comment: try removing duplicate dependencies of both compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1' and make the of same version , and in you layout for frame layout there is no need for setting orientation

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have come across this situation and the problem has been solved by upgrading the **Gradle version** i.e `3.5.1` to `3.5.3`.

> Note: This issue occurs with the Gradle version So you need to
>   downgrade or upgrade the version number

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio with Instant Run? Because this error seems very familliar to me.

Try to rebuild without Instant Run:

Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run -> uncheck "Enable instant run"

Still not working? Try to downgrade your Gradle to 1.2.3 just to see if that makes a difference:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

Comment: if i edited gradle version i can't sync my project I have this error message:
`Error:Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\Work\Android\Apps\Trivelgob2b\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.`

Comment: Did you deactivate instant run?